# Can we get product by SKU using Shopify Storefront GraphQL API(NOT ADMIN)?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I am stuck on this for more than two days now. I couldn't able to find any resources on this. There are many solutions by using ADMIN API but I don't have Admin access. Problem I am trying to solve is: I have only access to Product's SKU. I need to fetch all other information(title, price, description, featuredImage etc...) from Shopify using Storefront API. Here's the function to get product:

```
function loadProducts(items) {
    let products = [];

    items.forEach((item) => {
        const sku = item.id;
        if (sku !== "undefined") {
            /* TODO: Need to figure out this query*/
            const query = `{
         products(first: 1, query: "sku:<sku>") {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        id
        description
      }
    }
  }
       }`;

            const STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            const GRAPHQL_URL = 'https://<my-store>.myshopify.com/api/2021-01/graphql.json';
            const GRAPHQL_BODY = {

                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {
                    'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                'body': JSON.stringify({ query })

            }
            products.push(getData(GRAPHQL_URL, GRAPHQL_BODY));
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(products);
}
function getData(url, body) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url, body)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

I'd really appreciate if you can redirect me to the right direction. PLEASE NOT: I am only suppose to use Storefront API, not the ADMIN API. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query the products by SKU using the StoreFront API.

The available query params for the StoreFront products are:

- available_for_sale
- created_at
- product_type
- tag
- title
- updated_at
- variants.price
- vendor

So you can't do this only with the StoreFront API since the SKU is not exposed (like the Admin API).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way I can setup Admin API on the front end?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel using the admin API on the storefront is not recommended. You can expose your store to external attacks if you don't know what you are doing. But you can create a private app and use it's password as an access token to communicate to the Admin API, but you will need to disable all end points and leave only the products as view only without edit to prevent unwanted edits from third parties. But once again I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround if you tag all of your products with their SKUs and you can search for that instead.